# Compare ip address in php

Tags: php, mysql

I made a table in my mysql where I store the login details of users.
We store, ip address (as long2ip), username, sitename and time. What I would like to do is to check if a user is logged into a site with more than 2 different ip's.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to store the username and IP in the database? Otherwise we can only give very vague, generic answers. it certainly sounds like it would be very easy to do in PHP.

Comment: I should add that before I edited the question, it simply asked 'is this easy in PHP'. Hence the 'Yes, it's easy' answer and comment.

Comment: Checking if user has logged from more than 2 different IP ("logged with 3 IP") is not the same as comparing IP ("this IP is (or is not) the same as that IP").

Answer (score 4):

This should be fairly easy as long as you have the database stored version available. Some untested pseudocode:

```
$longIPdb = ip2long($ipfromdb);
$longRemote = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($longIPdb == $longRemote) echo "We're the same.";
else echo "We're from different IPs.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this should be done in SQL, not PHP:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) WHERE username='username';
```

If necessary this can be further restricted on time (`AND time > NOW()-3600`).
The result will be the number of different IP addresses the given user has in your database (in the given time frame, if specified).